# monacaで歩数計は作る方法はありますか？

Tags: monaca

プログラミング、アプリ開発ともに初心者です。

シンプルな歩数計を作りたいのですが、
どこかのblogでmonacaではバックグラウンドで動くアプリは作れないので、
歩数計とか無理だろうな、というような記述を見かけました。

他のアプリからデータを取得するなどして、歩数計を
作ることは出来ないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

できますよ！iOSなら比較的簡単にできます。
http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/healthkit　このプラグインを使用すればヘルスケアのデータを読み出すことができます（歩数、距離データ等）
外部プラグインを利用するには、Goldプランに入らなといけませんが、、、

Comment: お返事が遅くなり申し訳ありません。

なるほど、答えは有料プランにありましたか！(笑)
monacaで出来ない訳じゃない、ということが分かってスッキリしました。

ご回答ありがとうございました。